# Bad math delimiter in enumerate using enumitem

Tags: math-mode, enumitem

Please consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*$\star$]
\item ABC
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know why the code above is accepted, but code
with the corresponding LaTeX syntax `label=\arabic*\(\star\)`
results in an `bad math delimiter` error. One would expect
that LaTeX math environments are prefered over TeX math.

Ps. I have come across other answers were they point out
that one must match the environments properly, e.g. (...) or [...]
but this is true in our case.

Comment: And note that `\( ... \)` expands to `$ ... $` with some error checking. (I guess in the end the answer to your question is about expansion, but I don't know yet.) It is ok to use `$ ... $` in LaTeX documents. With `$$ ... $$` it is a bit different and you really should avoid that.

Comment: The commands `\(` and `\)` are not "robust" by default, whereas `$` is. Probably the simplest way to make `\(` and `\)` robust is to load the package [fixltx2e](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e).

Comment: Incidentally, which TeX distribution (and which vintage) do you have on your system? Starting with the 2015/01/01 version of the LaTeX2e format, it should no longer be necessary to load `fixltx2e` manually, i.e., the improvements contained in that package should by now be incorporated by default in the LaTeX2e format.

Comment: The math environment \ensuremath as [label=\arabic*\ensuremath{\star}] works perfectly

Comment: Incidentally, the [recommended method](http://www.texdev.net/2014/12/28/fixing-latex2e/) for loading `fixltx2e` is to issue the instruction `\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}` *before* `\documentclass...`.

Comment: @AmbikaVanchinathan Which is one of the cases where `\ensuremath` is good.

Comment: @egreg: Replacing the label in the given code with my label code instead of \\( ... \\) works perfectly

Comment: @AmbikaVanchinathan That's what I said! `;-)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely reason for

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*\(\star\)]
```

throwing a "bad math delimiter" error, whereas

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*$\star$]
```

does not, is that you're using an older LaTeX format (specifically, older than 2015/01/01), in which `\(` and `\)` are "fragile" commands (in the LaTeX jargon sense of the word). In contrast, `$` has been "robust" all along. Trouble lurks when fragile commands are used in the arguments of other commands.

I can think of two fixes (other, than, of course replacing `\(` and `\)` with `$` or a similarly "robust" method for entering and exiting math mode):

- Update your (pdf/Xe/Lua)LaTeX format to a version that is *more recent* than 2015/01/01. You can find out which version of the LaTeX format your system provides by looking at the first or second line of the .log file.

  Up-to-date LaTeX versions should not produce the error message you encounter. To wit, when I run your MWE on my system (MacTeX2015 pre-release, pdfLaTeX format 2015/05/30), I encounter no problems.
- If you're stuck with a TeX distribution for which you can't obtain an up-to-date version of the LaTeX format, you should load the `fixltx2e` package via the instruction

  ```
  \RequirePackage{fixltx2e}
  ```

  *before* executing `\documentclass...`. As the name of the package indicates, `fixltx2e` fixes various known quirks in the LaTeX format. Among the fixes -- you guessed it -- are instructions that make `\(` and `\)` "robust".

  Coming to think of it, if you're stuck with a pre-2015/01/01 version of LaTeX, it's probably *always* a good idea to load this package. (Versions of the LaTeX format more recent than 2015/01/01 incorporate the fixes provided by `fixltx2e`. Consequently, the latest version of the `fixltx2e` doesn't "do" anything anymore; if loaded, it just reports that "fixltx2e is not required with releases after 2015".)